# Connection Error when I do the integration of Paypal

Tags: java, paypal

I receive this error when I try to get an "accessToken":

I just implemented my code from this site: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

```
Caught exception while handling error responsejava.net.ConnectException: errno: 110 (Connection timed out), error: Connection timed out (local port 36807 to address 0.0.0.0, remote port 443 to address 173.0.82.78 (api.sandbox.paypal.com))
```

my code looks like this:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ClientService {


@GET
@Path("/processGetToken")

public Response processPayment() throws ServletException, PayPalRESTException {

Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
int status= 200;

String accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential("AQkquBDf1zctJOWGKWUEtKXm6qVhueUEMvXO_-MCI4DQQ4-LWvkDLIN2fGsd", "EL1tVxAjhT7cJimnz5-Nsx9k2reTKSVfErNQF-CmrwJgxRtylkGTKlU4RvrX", sdkConfig).getAccessToken();

return Response.status(status).entity(accessToken).build();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your firewall is not blocking the connection? It's timing out while attempting to connect, meaning that the application failed to connect to the api server.